# kABPersonPhoneProperty Only Detecting Home Phone Numbers

Tags: ios, addressbook, phone-number

I followed Apple's tutorial on obtaining a contact's phone number and it works great but it only detects phone numbers with the "Home" label. Here is my code:

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
NSString* phone = nil;
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                 kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
} else {
phone = @"[None]";
}
self.contactNumber.text = phone;
CFRelease(phoneNumbers); }
```

Anyone know why it is doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because this line

```
ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
```

tells it to get the first phone number, i.e "Home" number.

See this post:
[Access to people info in iPhone address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359296/access-to-people-info-in-iphone-address-book/17359801#17359801)